# Create custom zip file in python

Tags: python, zip

I'd like to create my own zip file archive that I can use in my own code i.e The archive wont be extractable in standard unzip applications but I just want to change the header to my own custom format e.g. .will . Any ideas? Should I just look at encrypting a standard zip?

NB: I'm NOT wanting to encrypt the data. I just want to "make my own zip format" which is essentially zip - just not extractable by a standard unzipper. For distribution of my own preferences of files/folders in an application (and not for prying eyes).

Comment: changing the header is not encryption. It's tinkering without knowledge what you are doing

Comment: If the goal is just to hide some zipped data, password protecting the zip sounds like a plan. `zip -e archive.zip super_secret_file.txt`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? And what is your deployment environment? (server, local machine, distributed to other users on CDROM etc) If the goal is to obfuscate code for intellectual property reasons, then Python may be a poor choice from the start; even the .pyc files are trivial to reverse engineer.

Comment: Its so I can distribute my own software files over the net - but I don't want any prying eyes i.e. I dont anyone to just "unzip". Equally the code needs to be lightweight hence thinking it would probably *not* be encryption that I required..

Answer (score -1):

If you really just want to "lock out" standard ZIP tools (which is not a good idea anyways),
precede a standard ZIP file with a custom header. Note that this is no encryption and the protection is really weak.

Pseudo-Code to "encrypt":

```
infile = open("yourzip.zip", "rb")
outfile = open("yourencrypt.nozip", "wb")
outfile.write("THISISNOZIP")
outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Pseudo-Code to "decrypt":

```
infile = open("yourencrypt.nozip", "rb")
outfile = open("yourzip.zip", "wb")
outfile.write(infile.read()[len("THISISNOZIP"):]
```

Comment: This won't work, not even close.  You can try it yourself -- but there is no header for zip files, and you can stick as much data on the front as you want.  Standard tools will expand the archive just fine.